# $_GET Returning Null

Tags: php, query-string

I feel like I'm doing some simple, stupid mistake. I have a very simple page that I'm using for testing. But I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Been searching for an answer for over an hour.

I realize that I could take the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and parse it, but I would prefer to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Maybe another pair of eyes can spot the problem.

Thanks.

P.S. In case this matters, this is on IIS (Windows Server 2008).

---

**On a URL with a query string, the $_GET is returning null.**
So, on this URL:

```
http://www...../test.php?id=test
```

where test.php contains:

```
<html><body>
<?php
if (isset($_get['id'])){
    echo "set";
}else
{
    echo "not set";
}
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_get['id']); 
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_request['id']);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
</body></html>
```

And my results are:

```
not set
NULL 
NULL 
string(13) "id=test" 
Array ( [id] => test )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$_get` != `$_GET`

PHP uses case-sensitive variable names. You always have to match the exact case.

Comment: See, I told you it was both simple & stupid. OK, I'm going to go jump off a cliff now. Or maybe just have a beer. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$_GET` instead of `$_get`